# Sacar dos valores de una consulta en function

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy intentando sacar de una function sacar dos valores, uno seria la url y otra el titulo.

```
var args = "Musica 2021";

async function searchYouTubeAsync(args) {

var video = await youtube.searchVideos(args.toString().replace(/,/g,' '));

return video.url;
}
```

Debería devolver la url y el titulo...

```
return video.url; // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPZoXLtkiko
return video.title; // MIX AÑO NUEVO 2021...

console.log(await searchYouTubeAsync(args));
```

No sé como añadir para que me devuelva dos valos en vez del return url solo, por ejemplo video[0] // la url y video[1] // el titulo.

Haber si me podéis echar una mano, he intentado modificando el return con dos valores pero solo me devuelve el primero.

Conclusión gracias al amigo era simplemente no especificar el valor añadirlo más tarde, y me estaba complicando...

Comment: solo tienes que hacer `return video;` o simplemente hacer un `return [video.url,video.title]` y al llamarlo seria `let [url,titulo] = searchYouTubeAsync(args);` y accedemos al url con `console.log(url)` e igual para el titulo

Comment: Si ya tienes ambas cosas que necesitas en la variable `video` tan solo devuélvelo (tal como te indican en la respuesta). Si de verdad *necesitas* devolver solo esas dos cosas, lo más rápido sería `return {url: video.url, title: video.title};`, entonces estarás devolviendo un objeto con los dos campos unicamente

Comment: No añadas resuelto a tu pregunta, si la respuesta de alguien te ayudó entonces lo correcto es marcarla como aceptada, si fuiste tu quien dio con la solución entonces publicala como respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías mas bien devolver el objeto de video, así:

```
return video;
```

Y luego utilizar `console.log(video.title)` y `console.log(video.url)` para acceder a estas propiedades. Como así:

```
const video = await searchYouTubeAsync(args);
console.log("Titulo: ", video.title);
console.log("URL: ", video.url);
```

También puedes usar [destructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const {titulo,url} = await searchYouTubeAsync(args);
console.log("Titulo: ", titulo;
console.log("URL: ", url);
```

Comment: Justo eso intentaba hacer, no sé porque me ofusque en que la respuesta estaba en el return y no en acortar la palabra. Muchas gracias, está resuelto.